# regex to exclude words for find tool

Tags: regex, linux, bash, find, regex-lookarounds

I try to find files with `find` util and I want to find all `*.js`-files except files in the special directories. I try to find with command:

```
find ./ -regex '\.((?\!node_modules).)*\.js'
```

But this scenario finds nothing.

This regex works for Sublime Text 3, where I've tested it.

P.S. I know about solving with another options like below. But I want to know how to solve the problem with regex

```
find ./ -path *node_modules -prune -o -name *.js
```

Comment: Try the following: `find . -name "*.js" | grep -v "<dir1>" | grep -v "dir2" ...` ("grep -v" means "not containing ...")

Answer (score 2, accepted):

You can't do it at the moment.

GNU Find supports several regex types, but none of them supports zero width assertions.

> ```
> -regextype type
>           Changes  the regular expression syntax understood by -regex and -iregex tests which occur later on the command line.  Currently-implemented types are emacs (this is the default), > posix-awk, posix-basic, posix-
>           egrep and posix-extended.
> ```

For your task you need the lookbehind assertion,
and it is not supported yet.

Another option for you is to use [find2perl](http://perldoc.perl.org/find2perl.html) that converts a find expression to a perl program,
that makes the same what the expression makes.

You could use this program to check if your expression will work with PCRE and look-ahead/look-behind assertions.

Answer (score 1):

It seems that the regex engine of your `find` implementation doesn't support lookaround. (See in `man find`, and you'll probably find what [@IgorChubin](https://stackoverflow.com/users/1458569/igor-chubin) explained.)

You can still use `! -regex` to exclude unwanted patterns, for example:

```
find . ! -regex '\./node_modules/.*' -name '*.js'
```

Comment: Thank you, it works (with escaping the exclamation point for bash). Bui it's not the exactly answer to my question, because it uses the another option ("!") of `find`, not only regex

Comment: You don't need to escape that `!` for Bash. And btw you *could* use another `-regex` instead of `-name` as `find . ! -regex '\./node_modules/.*' -regex '.*\.js'` but that's unnecessarily longer so I wouldn't recommend